# How do I remove words from a wordcloud?

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm creating a wordcloud using the wordcloud package in R, and the help of "[Word Cloud in R](http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2011/07/word-cloud-in-r.html)".

I can do this easily enough, but I want to remove words from this wordcloud.  I have words in a file (actually an excel file, but I could change that), and I want to exclude all these words, of which there are a couple hundred.  Any suggestions?

```
require(XML)
require(tm)
require(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)
ap.corpus=Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(as.character(data.merged2[,6]))))
ap.corpus=tm_map(ap.corpus, removePunctuation)
ap.corpus=tm_map(ap.corpus, tolower)
ap.corpus=tm_map(ap.corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
ap.tdm=TermDocumentMatrix(ap.corpus)
ap.m=as.matrix(ap.tdm)
ap.v=sort(rowSums(ap.m),decreasing=TRUE)
ap.d=data.frame(word = names(ap.v),freq=ap.v)
table(ap.d$freq)
```

Comment: Instead of or in addition to, the `stopwords("english")` add the stop words from the excel file as well.  You can combine vectors of words to make one vector of stop words.  These are excluded from the word cloud.

Answer (score 3):

@Tyler Rinker has given the answer, just add another line of `removeWords()`, but here's a bit more detail.

Let's say your excel file is called `nuts.xls` and has a single column of words like this

```
stopwords
peanut
cashew
walnut
almond
macadamia
```

In `R` you might proceed like this

```
     library(gdata) # package with xls import function
     library(tm)
     # now load the excel file with the custom stoplist, note a few of the arguments here 
     # to clean the data by removing spaces that excel seems to insert and prevent it from 
     # importing the characters as factors. You can use any args from read.table(), which is
     # handy
     nuts<-read.xls("nuts.xls", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)

     # now make some words to build a corpus to test for a two-step stopword removal process...
     words1<- c("peanut, cashew, walnut, macadamia, apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, and, or, but")
     words2<- c("peanut, cashew, walnut, almond, apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, if, then, on")
     words3<- c("peanut, walnut, almond, macadamia, apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, it, as, an")
     words.all<-data.frame(rbind(words1,words2,words3))
     words.corpus<-Corpus(DataframeSource((words.all)))

     # now remove the standard list of stopwords, like you've already worked out
     words.corpus.nostopwords <- tm_map(words.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
     # now remove the second set of stopwords, this time your custom set from the excel file, 
     # note that it has to be a reference to a character vector containing the custom stopwords
     words.corpus.nostopwords <- tm_map(words.corpus.nostopwords, removeWords, nuts$stopwords)

     # have a look to see if it worked
     inspect(words.corpus.nostopwords)
     A corpus with 3 text documents

     The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
     Available tags are:
          create_date creator 
     Available variables in the data frame are:
          MetaID 

     $words1
        , , , , apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, , , 

     $words2
        , , , , apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, , , 

     $words3
        , , , , apple, pear, orange, lime, mandarin, , ,
```

Success! the standard stopwords are gone, as are the words in the custom list from the excel file. Undoubtedly there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks to both Ben and the Tin Man.  Some sort of combination of the two worked out for me.  I did have trouble loading the xls with gdata because much if it was masked, so my problems turned out to be extra spacing of excel and cells with more than one word.  I appreciate it all though!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Convert the data you want to make a datacloud into a data frame.
Create a CSV file with the words you want to be eliminated and read it as a data frame. You can then make an `anti_join`:

```
allWords = as.data.frame(table(bigWords$Words))

wordsToAvoid = read.csv("wordsToDrop.csv")

finalWords = anti_join(allWords, wordsToAvoid, by = "Words")
```