# Remove words from string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to remove certain words from a data frame:

```
name    age words
James   34  hello, my name is James. 
John    30  hello, my name is John. Here is my favourite website https://stackoverflow.com
Jim 27  Hi! I'm another person whose name begins with a J! Here is something that should be filtered out: <filter>
```

---

```
df<-structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("James", 
"Jim", "John"), class = "factor"), age = c(34L, 30L, 27L), message = structure(1:3, .Label = c("hello, my name is James. ", 
"hello, my name is John. Here is my favourite website https://stackoverflow.com", 
"Hi! I'm another person whose name begins with a J! Here is something that should be filtered out: <filter>"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "age", "message"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I'm trying to remove all words containing matches to `http` or `filter`.

I would like to iterate over each row, split the string on white space and then ask whether the word contains either `http` or `<filter>` (or other words). If so, then I want to replace the word with a space.

There are a [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619941/how-do-i-remove-words-from-a-wordcloud) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940847/filter-a-column-based-on-a-list-of-words-in-r) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317226/how-to-filter-data-based-on-one-word-of-a-column-value-in-r) concerning removing words that **exatly match** another word, or list of words, but I can't find much on removing words that match some criteria (e.g. `http` or `www.`).

I've tried:

`gsub`, `!grepl` and `tm_map` approaches (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317226/how-to-filter-data-based-on-one-word-of-a-column-value-in-r)), but I can't get any of them to produce my expected output of:

```
name    age words
James   34  hello, my name is James. 
John    30  hello, my name is John. Here is my favourite website 
Jim 27  Hi! I'm another persoon whose name begins with a J! Here is something that should be filtered out:
```

Comment: The word "filtered" in your last row matches `filter` and should be removed, based on your explanations. Unless you mean `<filter>`.

Comment: @AntoniosK - you're right. I've updated the question

Comment: Cool. The answer below will definitely help you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove any non-whitespace chunks *containing* either `http` or `filter` (or other words) *as whole words* you may use `gsub` with the following *PCRE* regex (add `perl=TRUE` argument):

```
(?:\s+|^)\S*(?<!\w)(?:https?|<filter>)(?!\w)\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW2GJA/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\s+|^)` - 1+ wjhitespaces or start of string
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars as many as possible
- `(?<!\w)` - no word char allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:https?|<filter>)` - `http`, `https` or `<filter>`
- `(?!\w)` - no word char allowed immediately to the right of the current location (after the words in the alternation group)
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars as many as possible.

See an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/356bpA):

```
df<-structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("James", 
"Jim", "John"), class = "factor"), age = c(34L, 30L, 27L), message = structure(1:3, .Label = c("hello, my name is James. ", 
"hello, my name is John. Here is my favourite website https://stackoverflow.com", 
"Hi! I'm another persoon whose name begins with a J! Here is something that should be filtered out: <filter>"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "age", "message"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
df$message <- gsub("(?:\\s+|^)\\S*(?<!\\w)(?:https?|<filter>)(?!\\w)\\S*", "", df$message, perl=TRUE)
df$message
```

Result:

```
[1] "hello, my name is James. "                                                                         
[2] "hello, my name is John. Here is my favourite website"                                              
[3] "Hi! I'm another persoon whose name begins with a J! Here is something that should be filtered out:"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\s(https:\\S+|<filter>)", "", df$message)
```